# How to target the specific parent class a child div is nested within?

Tags: jquery, html

I need to hide the parent div (i.e., .post) when the child div (i.e., post-title) is empty. However, I don't want to hide the other child div if it contains content.

This is what I have going on:

```
<div id="latest">
    <div class="post">
        <div class="post-content">
            <div class="post-title"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <div class="post-content">
            <div class="post-title"><h2>Hello!</h2></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(".post-title:empty").parent($(".post")).hide();
```

Comment: `$(".post-title:empty").parents('.post').hide();` or better `$(".post-title:empty").closest('.post').hide();`

Comment: @Pete `parents()` will, updated

Comment: It's `parents('.post')`

Comment: @Satpal yep, but your original comment didn't say that did it, plus you better make sure that there are not other elements further up the tree with a class of post if you use parents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `closest()` to get the closest parent with the class of post

```
$(".post-title:empty").closest('.post').hide();
```

```js
 $(".post-title:empty").closest('.post').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="latest">
  <div class="post">
    <div class="post-content">
      <div class="post-title"></div>
      <p>content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <div class="post-content">
      <div class="post-title">
        <h2>Hello!</h2>
      </div>
       <p>content hello</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.parents('.post')` is better than `.closest()` on this case

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Why? What's the difference?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude, Actually `closest()` is better as it stops traversal when element is found.

Comment: You're right, it stops and is better performance. I used to use `parents()` because the order on the returning elements is the DOM order descendant, so the first item is the closest parent. However, both are valid.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I would delete your first comment as it is completely wrong

Comment: _completely wrong_ ? I'm not agree with that, only is different opinion. However if you think is better to remove the comment, no problem man!

Comment: @madalin ivascu, beautiful -- thank you so much! Thank you everyone else for your input!